# Text field with dynamically generated datalist using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to generate a dynamic  for a text input. When ever the text input will be clicked, jQuery will find previously inputted data for the current user and append them on the corresponding datalist. Here is the markup i have right now:

```
<div class="form-inline">
  <input type="text" list="suggestions" id="search-input">
  <datalist id="suggestions">
  </datalist>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="search-submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$('#search-input').on('click', function(){
   for(var x = 0; x<localStorage.length; x++){
    var key = localStorage.key(x);
    var item = localStorage.getItem(key);
    console.log(username+'-'+key+'-'+item);//username is a global var that holds the name of the currently logged in user
    if(key == username) {
      $('#suggestions').append('<option value="'+item+'">');
    }
  }
});
```

This is not doing anything so far. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors?  If so, what are they?  Are you getting into the key == username check?  Is the value correct if you are?  Are you using a browser that doesn't support the datalist tag?  The more info you provide in your question, the better the answers you will get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to search through everything in localstorage if you already know the key:

```
$('#search-input').on('click', function(){
   if(localStorage.getItem(username)) {
     $('#suggestions').append('<option value="'+localStorage.getItem(username)+'">');
   }
  }
});
```

if this doesn't work but console.log `localStorage.getItem(username)` does then make sure the `$('#suggestions')` selector is working too.

Comment: Yes, a mistype on the suggestions tag was the problem. Everything else was okay.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use `click` when referring to a textbook,

instead use `change`, `focus`, `keyup`, `keydown`